# single Transaction across Hibernate session and plain jdbc

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jdbc, transactions

Is it possible to use a single Transaction boundary for Hibernate Session and a plain JDBC query. ? 
The database and the datasource configurations are similar for both.

Comment: @RomanC this is pretty common.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Use `HibernateTransactionManager`. Below is taken from its [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.x/api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/HibernateTransactionManager.html)

> This implementation is appropriate for applications that solely use
>   Hibernate for transactional data access, but it also supports direct
>   data source access within a transaction (i.e. plain JDBC code working
>   with the same DataSource). This allows for mixing services that access
>   Hibernate (including transactional caching) and services that use
>   plain JDBC (without being aware of Hibernate)! Application code needs
>   to stick to the same simple Connection lookup pattern as with
>   DataSourceTransactionManager (i.e. DataSourceUtils.getConnection or
>   going through a TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy).
>
> Note that to be able to register a DataSource's Connection for plain
>   JDBC code, this instance needs to be aware of the DataSource (see
>   setDataSource). The given DataSource should obviously match the one
>   used by the given SessionFactory. To achieve this, configure both to
>   the same JNDI DataSource, or preferably create the SessionFactory with
>   LocalSessionFactoryBean and a local DataSource (which will be
>   autodetected by this transaction manager).